# Can 'to' be omitted in "honor to be here"

Tags: phrase-usage

I heard a woman said in a news program *honor be here*. I might misheard it but that is why I want to check it here.

Question: can **to** be omitted in such phrases like, honor to be here, nice to meet you, and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, **to** cannot be dropped there, not unless the phrase is **nice *being* here** or **nice *meeting* you**.

The choice is between the two non-finite clauses, infinitival or participial:

to be ...

being ...